Is the following family of complex functions normal?
Consider the following family of holomorphic functions defined on the domain $ \Omega = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1 \} $:

$ g(z) = 0 $
$ U = \{z : -2 < \text{Re}g(z) < 2 \} $

Is the family of holomorphic functions described above a normal family? In other words, does every sequence $ \{ f_{n} \}_{n} $ in the family admit a subsequence that converges locally uniformly to a function $ f \in \mathbb{C}^{n} $?
I couldn't find any counterexample, and I suspect the proposition could be true. To have a counterexample I should find a sequence of function that is not locally uniformly bounded.

Did you mean $-2 < \text{Re},g(z) < 2 $

@geetha290krm yes, sorry. No because  $g_n(0)\neq 0$.

Do you know Montel's theorem?

Yes, I do. Locally uniform boundness is a necessary and sufficient condition for normality.

Let $\mathcal{F}=\{f\in\mathcal{H}(\Omega):f(0)=0, \ -2<\text{Re}(f(z))<2\}$. We are going to see that this family is uniformly bounded over compact sets, and then Montel's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel%27s_theorem) will give us that $\mathcal{F}$ is normal. Consider the isomorphism from $U=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:-2<\text{Re}(z)<2\}$ to the disk given by $\phi(z)=\frac{e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}z}-1}{e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}z}+1}$. Let $K\subset\Omega$ be a compact subset. We then see that, given $f\in\mathcal{F}$, $\phi \circ f$ satisfies the hypotheses of Schwarz lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma), and therefore $|(\phi \circ f)(0)|\leq|z| \ \forall z\in\Omega$. Use that there exists $r>0$ such that $|z|\leq r \ \forall z\in K$ to get your uniform bound over $K$ and you are done.
